# Nvchad: Is it possible to reuse existing .vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc, nvchad

I checked the documentation but couldn't find an answer to this basic question: Is it possible to reuse my existing `.vimrc` file in Nvchad? Currently, nvchad ignores my settings in `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NvChad has some exit point for customization. In particular it loads the `.lua` file in the `lua\custom` folder.

You could edit the `lua\custom\init.lua` file in that folder with the following content:

```
local vimrc = vim.fn.stdpath "config" .. ".vimrc"
vim.cmd('source ' .. vimrc)
```

Assuming your `.vimrc` is in the nvim folder (`~/AppData/local/nvim` on Windows)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. There is one issue though. I created `lua/custom/vimrc.lua` and put the lines above. It didn't work. Then I put the above lines into `lua/custom/chadrc.lua` file. It worked. Maybe should I source `vimrc.lua` file somewhere?

Comment: I believe the correct way is to edit `lua\custom\init.lua` I have tested at my end and it seems to work.